# toggle button with font awesome and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this was going to be simple, but I am having a bit of hard time getting this to work. I am able to toggle once using .show and .hide, but not able to toggle back.

all the help would be appreciated.

here is the code:

```
<div class="middle">
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x active" id="on" style="display:none;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x fa-rotate-180 inactive" id="off" ></i>
</div> 


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.middle').click(function(){
        $('.inactive').show();
        $('.active').hide();

    })

    .click(function(){
        $('.inactive').hide();
        $('.active').show();

    });

});
```

I also have a pen of it here: http://codepen.io/lucky500/pen/qdZPLe

Comment: Hey Mohamed .... I did tried those methods, but they did not give me the desired result. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one approach is to use `toggle`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.middle').click(function() {
        $('.inactive, .active').toggle();
  });
});
```

**http://codepen.io/miguelmota/pen/zGqPOX**

Answer (score 3):

Why not simplify this a bit by using a single element with [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

http://jsbin.com/ceyilucuya/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$('.toggler').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-rotate-180 on');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your HTML it a little funky, however I found a dirty fix to your problem. The following code i repeat is a dirty fix, but it works.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwyEdq

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    i = 0;

    $(".fa-toggle-on").click(function() {
        if ( i == 0) {
            $('.inactive').hide();
            $('.active').show();
            i++;
        }
        else if ( i == 1) {
            $('.inactive').show();
            $('.active').hide();
            i = 0;
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="middle">
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x active" id="on" style="display:none;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x fa-rotate-180 inactive" id="off" ></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.middle {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.active {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Could `i` be a boolean?

Answer (score 1):

Generally and simply it works like this:
You can use this in general purposes.

```js
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('i').click(function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus-square fa-minus-square');
                });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the fontawesome icon is a nice idea, however the browser may show some change in the vertical positioning since the icon has different transparent margins with respect to the visible pixels.

I combined the solutions of @miguel-mota and @oka.

Only one fontawesome tag is needed, the classes are switched in the on click function for the class .toggler.
Make sure to use the each function to apply multiple transformations.

JS

```
 $('.toggler').on('click', function () {
          $(".my-button").each(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('fa-toggle-off');
            $(this).toggleClass('fa-toggle-on');
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
          })
      });
```

CSS

```
.toggler {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}
.active {
    color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="toggler">
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-2x inactive my-button"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin worked well for me: https://github.com/hurkanaras/Hurkan-Switch-Plugin

An example:

```
$('[data-toggle="hurkanSwitch"]').hurkanSwitch({
    'width':'90px',
    'offConfirm': function(r) { return confirm('Are you sure you want to disable this?'); },
    'on': function(e) { toggle(e, 'enable'); },
    'off': function(e) { toggle(e, 'disable'); },
    'onColor': 'green',
    'offColor': 'red',
    'className': 'switch-toggle' //I changed the font size with this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <i id='checkboxAbcToggle' class='far fa-square cursorIcon'></i> Show Abc
</body>
```

=================

```
$('#checkboxAbcToggle').click(function () {

    // Toaster.top('toggleClass');
    UiUx.setCheckbox('#checkboxAbcToggle');
});

let Key = {
    uncheckedSquare: 'fa-square',
    checkedSquare: 'fa-check-square',
}

let UiUx = {};
UiUx.setCheckbox = function (checkboxIcon_jqId) {

    let checkboxIconElement = $(checkboxIcon_jqId);
    let isChecked = checkboxIconElement.hasClass(Key.checkedSquare);

    if (isChecked === true) {

        checkboxIconElement.removeClass(Key.checkedSquare);
        checkboxIconElement.addClass(Key.uncheckedSquare);
    }
    else {

        checkboxIconElement.removeClass(Key.uncheckedSquare);
        checkboxIconElement.addClass(Key.checkedSquare);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.rotate{
     transform:rotate(180deg);
      color:black
    }
```

jquery

```
$('.fa-toggle-on').on('click',function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('rotate')
      });
```